# Django NoReverseMatch Error when passing arguments on redirect

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views, django-reversion

Hi im trying to redirect from one view function to another and passing a list of lists as argument.

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^checkFiles/', views.checkFiles, name='checkoutFiles'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^login', views.loginview, name='loginview'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logoutview, name='logoutview'),
    url(r'^confirm_files/', views.upload, name='confirm_file'),
    url(r'^upload/', views.del_files, name='del_files'),

]
```

**views.py**

for redirecting from views.upload to views.checkoutFiles i'm using this command

```
return redirect(reverse('checkoutFiles', kwargs={'ACCEPTED_FILES':ACCEPTED_FILES}))
```

...

```
def checkFiles(request, ACCEPTED_FILES):
  print ACCEPTED_FILES
  return render(request, 'confirm_files.html', {
      'ACCEPTED_FILES': ACCEPTED_FILES
  })
```

and im getting this error message

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'checkoutFiles' with keyword arguments '{'ACCEPTED_FILES': [[u't2_r0Oqwl7.txt', '0.98 KB', u'text/plain']]}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['checkFiles/']
```

django version: 1.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call reverse, Django follows what you have in urls.py. In there you don't have any parameters specified in the regular expression for `checkoutFiles`. For example:

```
url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive, name='year-archive'),
```

In this example you can call:

```
reverse('year-archive', args=[datetime.datetime.today().year])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example

In your code you must specify what are the parameters you'll receive in that URL.

```
url(r'^checkFiles/(?P<extension>[\w]+)/$', views.checkFiles, name='checkoutFiles'),
```

Although it would not be a good idea doing this kind of validation through a URL.

#### Edit #2

If you want to have something in the URL, you can use a `GET` parameter:

Whenever you redirect you can do something like this:

```
return redirect(reverse('checkoutFiles') + '?files={}'.format(ACCEPTED_FILES))
```

In the view where you are redirected to, you can get the values with

```
request.GET.get('files', '')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Comment: still having the same error...  i'm trying to display the values of the list 'ACCEPTED_FILES' on a different url.. How would you suggest me do it? thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a `GET` parameter. Whenever you redirect you can do something like this: `return redirect(reverse('checkoutFiles') + '?files={}'.format(ACCEPTED_FILES))`. In the view where you are redirected to, you can get the values with `request.GET.get('files', '')`.

Comment: And you are getting the error because your view has a different variable name. Instead of `extension` use `ACCEPTED_FILES`: `url(r'^checkFiles/(?P<ACCEPTED_FILES>[\w]+)/$', views.checkFiles, name='checkoutFiles'),`

Comment: i used the GET option and works fine! does it worth to debug or it's better to use a GET parameter? which one is better solution (and if you have time, explain why :P )?
thanks for your time!

Comment: What does accepted files mean? Is it the name of the files uploaded in another view? Their extensions? I still haven't understood what you want to do with this logic. I mean it is a bad idea because the user can modify the GET parameters manually and you might not be able to check if the values are true or not. And remember to mark the question as correct if it solved the error you had. :)

Comment: accepted files is a list of filenames where uploaded by the user in previous step

Comment: That's dangerous. Given the following situation: User uploads file_1, file_2 and file_3. You accept only file_1 and file_2. However, the user intentionally  adds file_3 in the GET URL, because he can do that. You'll accept all three files even though that was not the idea. I would suggest using another function to do this validation, which would accept the request (among other things) as parameter. From this function you can redirect to wherever you want and still do the validation, without touching the URL.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a namespace in you project urls.py file and also in below code
Example:
project_name/urls.py

```
url(r'^appname/', include('appname.urls', namespace='namespace')),
```

views.py

```
 return redirect(reverse('namespace:checkoutFiles', kwargs={'ACCEPTED_FILES':ACCEPTED_FILES}))
```

Comment: i have only one app and url snippet belongs to project urls.py... still not fixed. tnx for your answer

Comment: You urls pattern doesnot take any arguments
url(r'^checkFiles/', views.checkFiles, name='checkoutFiles'),